# Web Storage for Android app

Tags: android, cloud, storage

Seems like it's difficult to get information on this subject, but what I would like to do is allow my android app to access image data stored online. What is the best way to achieve this such that I can bulk upload images to the webserver and access individual images on demand from my android app. Do I need a paid hosting service, ftp? While I am familiar with android I am not so well versed in networking/online aspects. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use [Dropbox Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync).

This requires the user to login to a dropbox account from your app though, but will make it very easy to view/add/remove images from both PC and device.

Have been working well for me.

Another, maybe not so obvious, solution could be [parse.com](http://www.parse.com)

You could of course create your own solution using a server and possibly ftp, or just regular http.

I just think that the above solutions may be preferable as they already have Android specific API's in place which means that you need not to worry about the many details about storage and communication.